# How use jQuery inline?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code:

```
<p id = 'drop1' style='color:#008cba; background-color:#fffF00;' 
onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()" title="See more">
Hi, my name is text 1.
</p>
```

that works.

But, I'd like to write it in `jQuery`. I tried:

```
<p id = 'drop2' style='color:#008cba; background-color:#fffF00;' 
$(this).attr('See more')>
Hi, my name is text 2.
</p>
```

Doesn't work.

Is there a way to write a `jQuery` only inline form?

Comment: Your second example is nonsense. Check what actually `show()`/`hide()` does (e.g. `$(this).show()` and `$(this).hide()`). Now you try to get attribute named `See more`

Comment: Sorry, I think I've improved my example now. The value inside `attr('See more')` doesn't work inline. Can you explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting code inline with HTML elements in general. It's just as easy to incorporate a script element and a proper event handler. However, I suspect that this is what you're after:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="drop2" style="color: #008cba; background-color: #fffF00;" 
    onmouseover="$(this).text('See more')"
    onmouseout="$(this).text('Hi, my name is text 2')">
  Hi, my name is text 2
</p>
```

The reason your example doesn't work is because jQuery's `attr()` method, when passed a single argument, attempts to *retrieve* the value of that attribute. There's no such attribute in your HTML.